# iOS Instagram login every time issue

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication, instagram

I am using instagram API in my client's app. This is a kind of a social networking app with profiles for each user. In this app, there is a section which displays instagram recent pictures of a person on their profile page. The issue is that I'm having to log the user in every time they go to view the profile in the instagram section. Can we have it so the user only has to login once and never again?

In other apps like Tinder, we login only once and then our profile is connected to instagram - even if you close the app. This means the app is either storing instagram credentials or the pictures. But latest documentation on instagram developer portal says don't store login credentials or pictures. How can I mimic this behaviour in our app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the login purpose, you can retrieve the `access token` for the particular use which you can store and for the every data retrieval request you can use that access token to get data without making user login again till the access token is valid

to get an access token you can follow the Instagram guide : [Instagram: User Authentication](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

Which is like

- Direct the user to our authorization URL. If the user is not logged
  in, they will be asked to log in. The user will be asked if they
  would like to grant your application access to her Instagram data.
- Client Side login

For the images for another user,
If you want the public feed of the user you can get directly if you already have the username of the Instagram user by making a get request without need of authentication/access token

```
https://www.instagram.com/{user-name of Instagram user for which you have to retrieve the media}/media/
```

Ex: https://www.instagram.com/instagram/media/ , this will return json with the public feed images

Comment: Thanks so much! That was helpful. Question- if someones profile has private feed and I don't follow that person, can you I see their feed using Instagram API using an access token?

Comment: no mostly, I didn't try that myself but according to the privacy policy of Instagram, you will not get private media of user which you are not following